# Old computer with mint 4 (debbie) rebooting after some usage time

Tags: linux-mint

I've installed LinuxMint debbie, LMDE 4 32bits, in my aunt's computer.
It runs smoothly and no partition configuration was manually made, just a plain wipe and install provided by Mint itself.
The computer boots fine, runs fine everything, but sometimes it just reboots!
It can't be used for more than a few minutes.. I've tracked it's temperature with `sensors`, never passed the 50ºC. Also I've tested the hardware stuff by putting the pc in BIOS mode and awaiting for hours, but it didn't reboot. Also, this didn't happen with the old SO (windows xp).
Where should I get info about the problem within the system?
There's nothing specific being done before the reboot, so there isn't a pattern there also.

Comment: Have you put it through memtest? If it fails, it's old and has been through many heat cycles. Just go ahead and re-seat the RAM (and feel free to re-seat the rest - though I'd skip re-seating the CPU). Also, anything in the logs? I'd check those. You can also try adding things like 'irqpoll' to GRUB.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a not a newbie in Linux but I'm still not an expert. 
What do you mean by "it has been through many heat cycles"? What is a "re-seat" of the RAM and the CPU (just take off and put it back on?)? And what irqpoll does?

Comment: Re-seat means physically remove the RAM and push it back in the slots to make sure they're snug. You can do that with video and audio cards too. Second, check your error logs - you may find errors that lead you to a solution, of which irqpoll added to GRUB may work, it was merely an example. If you know the errors, you can narrow down the solutions. Memtest can be easily Googled and is where I'd start first. As for heat cycles, it's an old computer. It has been turned off and on many times. Each time, it gets hot while it is on and cools when it is off. That impacts hardware. Make sense?

Comment: Ok, it makes sense hahah thanks! I'll check all this!